# In openssl, if I decrypt using a wrong password it just tells "bad decrypt" without showing the output. Is there a way to show it anyway?

Tags: encryption, openssl

I encrypted a sample test file using:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -in test -nosalt -out encprova.aes128
```

Then, to decrypt:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -d -in encprova.aes128 -nosalt
```

and if I write the correct pw, it prints the correct content of "test". but if I write an incorrect pw, it prints:

```
bad decrypt
009E69DB997F0000:error:1C800064:Provider routines:ossl_cipher_unpadblock:bad decrypt:providers/implementations/ciphers/ciphercommon_block.c:124:
```

**I understand that openssl knows if a decryption goes well by just looking at the padding: if padding is not present that means that decryption went bad.**

**But is there a way to force openssl to see the decrypted content anyway?**

Comment: You can actually disable padding with `-nopad`, then the (wrong) plaintext generated with the wrong password will be returned.

Comment: @Topaco no, in CBC is not possibile to disable padding. I can do that with aes-128-ctr instead, and it let me see the decrypted wrong message. But again, can't do that with aes-128-cbc because padding is mandatory

Comment: You can always disable padding when **de**crypting, even with block cipher modes such as CBC.

Comment: see this example online: https://onlinegdb.com/uEzq2dHRD